# How is this syntax causing an error with parsing my gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, terminal

I am following http://installfest.railsbridge.org/ and I'm to edit my Gemfile and change

```
gem 'sqlite3'
```

to

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

I did that and now it's telling me to type

```
push to heroku master
```

and I'm getting an error message saying:

```
Gemfile syntax error on line 7: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block
on line 9: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

I'm on Windows and I JUST installed everything today so I have the latest versions of everything.  Does anybody know why this is happening?

Here's the Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: Does it work locally when you run `bundle install`? I do not see anything wrong with the lines you posted, but the error might be caused by something **before** that, can you post your entire Gemfile? Also, I'd recommend you to use pg also in dev and test, it's always better if you use the same DB in all your environments (makes your life much easier when you need to debug).

Comment: I second that @taglia. Having different DB's in different environments is a disaster waiting to happen. Please post your entire Gemfile.

Comment: Everything I'm trying is being done locally.  Haven't gotten far enough to putting things out to a server yet.

Comment: @taglia what do you mean use pg in dev and test?  I just started to learn this today so I know nothing about the language yet.

Comment: I mean install postgres on your dev machine, remove the `group :development, :test` block, and move `gem 'pg'` out of the production group. Then you will be using postgres on all your environments.

Comment: so you're saying I should eliminate the production group and put everything inside the development one?